# spark-shell: Invalid initial heap size

Tags: apache-spark

I am running spark-1.6.1 on Linux, and when I set SPARK_DRIVER_MEMORY in spark-env.sh to 4g and run spark-shell, I get this:

```
Invalid initial heap size: -Xms4g
The specified size exceeds the maximum representable size.
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

How can I increase the maximum representable size?
and if I set **SPARK_DRIVER_MEMORY=3g** (or lower than 3g),everything is ok.
P.S. My computer's memory is more than 4g, and my jdk is 1.6 and it is 64 bits.

Comment: did you ever resolve this issue?  I am running into a similar problem

Answer (score 1):

If you are running Spark on Yarn then
Spark.driver.memory should be smaller than yarn container memory 
Because  spark applications will run inside yarn container

Spark.driver.memory(spark-default.conf) <  yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb(yarn-site.xml)

for more details you can see [here](https://linode.com/docs/databases/hadoop/install-configure-run-spark-on-top-of-hadoop-yarn-cluster/)